# How to add types for a typescript function that takes in an array of generics

Tags: typescript

please see code sample below- i'd like some typesafety around the type of array entries that  `resetHistory` takes in, but it's not creating a type error where i'd like it to! appreciate any tips.

[typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQN4FgBQUUYCA9gGYCWANhAFw5QCuqECAkgCYOrAKUA7AOZQAvgG4CRABalkEMHCH1mAzhCoCInSYSitgwQUNQNsUYHABGDAESLUqAO6kEnW1AA+Ue2Sq0PCQIg-AIAejCoAThKADdoOEMIZDBgKESLcGMLaWhpSl5XEHSEIQJyJgEAYyNSASgECAMACQLgIoAeAGkoCAAPYAg1dABrCBAKWEQUVAA+AAopKHzChBAzKJQVLvFiabQGeCQ0AG0ugF0xE-OCAEocJYioADpX4IICRpa2ovmTpfM0Xkdlk8kUylsABo9sdTKp1JptGJIQDNsCfCQKDQIFCYTMNiw2Fw7ABGABMAGYACyBZGooEqWwGIzCVC4xSwgmsDjcHx9fm00TQp4dAC0oqglCgTjgAjSwBWFlIUCsCUykDYZAQ0NlnCgdWoxTgVSqCjS5ksNgxcEcLjcHm8vixATEBHOt10QA)

```js
type Params = {
  profile: { userId: string };
  homepage: undefined;
  settings: { tab: "password" | "profile" };
};

// naive attempt at typing the history arg
function resetHistory<K extends keyof Params>(
  history: { name: K; params: Params[K] }[]
) {
  // ...
}

resetHistory([
  { name: "homepage", params: undefined },
  { name: "profile", params: { userId: "1234" } },
  { name: "settings", params: { userId: "xxx" } }, // <-- i want this to be a typeerror, and only accept { tab: "password" | "profile" }
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is a union of all possible pairings.  We can create that with a mapped type.

```
type HistoryEntry = {
  [K in keyof Params]: Params[K] extends undefined 
      ? { name: K; params?: undefined; }
      : { name: K; params: Params[K]; }
}[keyof Params]
```

For each key of the `Params` object, the acceptable value is an object with a `name` that matches that key and a `params` that matches the `Params` value for that key.  That is `{ name: K; params: Params[K]; }`.

I am adding a conditional check `Params[K] extends undefined` to allow you to omit the `params` entirely if they are `undefined`.  So you can just pass `{ name: "homepage" }`.

Our `resetHistory` function is no longer generic.  It accepts an array where all entries are of type `HistoryEntry`.

```
function resetHistory( history: HistoryEntry[] ) {
```

This gives us all of the errors that we want:

```
resetHistory([
  { name: "homepage" }, // ok
  { name: "profile", params: { userId: "1234" } }, // ok
  { name: "settings" }, // error: params is missing
  { name: "settings", params: { userId: "xxx" } }, // error: tab is missing from params
  { name: "settings", params: { tab: "password" } } // ok
]);
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mL9q2W)